# Beautiful Soup and extracting a div work for one site but not for the other

Tags: python

**TOPIC CLOSED**

I have this part of the code

```
containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class' : 'product-count d-flex align-items-center'})
output = ''
for container in containers:

    price = container.find('span',{'class':'lang'}).text.replace(",", "") if container.find('span',{'class':'lang'}) else ""
```

that extract the value that I need from this HTML page

```
<div class="product-count d-flex align-items-center">
<span class="icon-military_tech" style="color: #FFCF57; font-size: 16px"></span>&nbsp;
<span class="lang">bought 24 times</span>
</div>
```

The result is **bought 24 times**

BUT for other site when the HTML code is

```
<div data-v-fd0de2e2=""><div data-v-fd0de2e2="" class="product-features"><!----> <div data-v-fd0de2e2=""><span data-v-fd0de2e2="" class="sold_products_count">bought 53 times</span></div></div> <!----> <!----> <div data-v-fd0de2e2="" class="product-meta"><div data-v-fd0de2e2="" class="product-sku"><strong data-v-fd0de2e2="">product code: </strong> <span data-v-fd0de2e2="">1200100045</span></div> <br data-v-fd0de2e2=""> <div data-v-fd0de2e2="" class="product-sku"><strong data-v-fd0de2e2="">weight: </strong> <span data-v-fd0de2e2="" style="direction: ltr; display: inline-block;">
                                        0 kg
                                    </span></div> <br data-v-fd0de2e2=""> <!----></div></div>
```

This modified python code gives empty file result

```
    containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class' : 'product-features'})
    output = ''
    for container in containers:

        price = container.find('span',{'class':'sold_products_count'}).text.replace(",", "") if container.find('span',{'class':'sold_products_count'}) else ""
```

The needed result for the last site is **bought 53 times**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code loops over all of `containers` before exiting, and overwrites `price` each time, so the eventual value of `price` is the one from the last 'container', whether or not that contains the data you were looking for.

You can break out of the loop once you've found the value you need, like this:

```
   containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class' : 'product-features'})
   output = ''
   for container in containers:
        price = container.find('span',{'class':'sold_products_count'}).text.replace(",", "") if container.find('span',{'class':'sold_products_count'}) else ""
        if price:
              break
   print(price)
```

Comment: thank you dear slothrop, but still not working. Full code added to the post above with example link

Comment: I tried the full code - but the example URL doesn't seem to contain any of the example HTML.  When I download that URL I don't see any "product-features" and so on.